# running function after res.send

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to run this code

```
module.exports = async (req, res, next) => {

    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/javascript');

    const response = {};

    res.status(200).render('/default.js', { response });

    await fn(response);
};
```

`fn` is a function that calls an api to a service that will output to the client something. but its dependent on the `default.js` file to be loaded first. How can do something like

```
res.render('/default.js', { response }).then(async() => {
    await fn(response);
};
```

tried it, but doesn't seem to like the `then()`

also, `fn` doesn't return data to the client, it calls an api service that is connected with the web sockets opened by the code from `default.js` that is rendered.

do i have to make an ajax request for the `fn` call and not call it internally?

any ideas?

Comment: just return the response, and call your fn outside (catch the response in a then and process it later)

Comment: can you post an example?

Comment: ` return response; ` instead of `await fn(response)`. And in the code which calls your async function (i name it myFunction), you can do `let response = await myFunction(....); response = fn(response); `

Comment: oh , `fn` calls a service that send a `webhook` response that is captured by another route. right now i have to make an `ajax` call to fire off `fn`, but i want to avoid the `ajax` and just call the `fn route` directly after the `js` is loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you call `res.render()`, you can send no more data to the client, the http response has been sent and the http connection is done - you can't send any more to it.  So, it does you no good to try to add something more to the response after you call `res.render()`.

It sounds like you're trying to put some data INTO the script that you send to the browser.  Your choices for that are to either:

1. Get the data you need to with `let data = await fn()` before you call `res.render()` and then pass that to `res.render()` so your template engine can put that data into the script file that you send the server (before you send it). 
   You will need to change the script file template to be able to do this so it has appropriate directives to insert data into the script file and you will have to be very careful to format the data as Javascript data structures.
2. Have a script in the page make an ajax call to get the desired data and then do your task in client-side Javascript after the page is already up and running.

---

It looks like it might be helpful for you to understand the exact sequence of things between browser and server.

1. Browser is displaying some web page.
2. User clicks on a link to a new web page.
3. Browser requests new web page from the server for a particular URL.
4. Server delivers HTML page for that URL.
5. Browser parses that HTML page and discovers some other resources required to render the page (script files, CSS files, images, fonts, etc...)
6. Browser requests each of those other resources from the server
7. Server gets a request for each separate resource and returns each one of them to the browser.
8. Browser incorporates those resources into the HTML page it previously downloaded and parsed.
9. Any client side scripts it retrieved for that page are then run.

So, the code you show appears to be a route for one of script files (in step 5 above).  This is where it fits into the overall scheme of loading a page.  Once you've returned the script file to the client with `res.render()`, it has been sent and that request is done.  The browser isn't connected to your server anymore for that resource so you can't send anything else on that same request.

Comment: after the `render` cal the js code is rendered. i then want to make an ajax call to call another route, but i was looking to see how to prevent an ajax call and just call the function directly after the the render is called. the `fn` doesn't return data, it makes an api call do a service that is connected with web sockets to the js code outputed

Comment: @eli- Well, you have no way of knowing when the webSocket in the client page is actually connected from within this route.  If it's the JS code you're serving that opens the webSocket, there will be a delay.  You send the JS code, it has to get transmitted, the browser receives it, the browser parses it, the browser runs other JS that's sequentially before it, then finally the browser runs that Javascript that was downloaded here in this route.  You have no way of knowing that timing from the server.

Comment: @eli - I'd also suggest you make a significant edit to your question to explain that this is what you're actually trying to do.  Your comment here was way better than what you have in your question.  You're more likely to get other people helping in the  desired direction if you add a lot more clarity to your question for the exact steps you have now and what you would like to change. None of that was clear to me by what you put in your question.  I will probably delete my answer in a bit since it doesn't appear to be what you were actually trying to ask about.